# datatables colmns stuck on width 173px

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to make a table with search features, i'm using DataTable, but i cant seem to be able to make any changes on the columns width, it's stuck on 173px.

Here is an example: https://codepen.io/RidaTazi/pen/wvXEado

What i want to do is to make the columns auto adjust to fit in the table with no scroll.

My config:

```
    var table = $('#table').DataTable({
      "lengthMenu": [5, 25, 50, 75, 100],
      "pageLength": 5,
      deferRender: true,
      scrollX: false,
      initComplete: function () {
        // Apply the search
        this.api()
          .columns()
          .every(function () {
            var that = this;
            $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change clear', function () {
              if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                that.search(this.value).draw();
              }
            });
          });
      },
    });
```

i tried this toom but it doesnt work:

```
      "columnDefs": [
         { "width": "5px", targets: '_all' }
      ],
```

Comment: You can experiment with the width of your input fields - e.g. `<input type="text" size="1" ...>`. That's probably not sufficient to get you what you want - you probably have too many input fields to fit in anything except a very wide viewport.

Comment: And then you may need to force line breaks for the actual content you want to display... So for each problem you solve, you may hit another one when you use realistic data. Just a guess.

Comment: yes, the input size is the one responsible for the weird behavior, should be set too. Thanks!